# How to Print File in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

How to print a specified file in WPF using PrintDialog.PrintDocument() method?

I want to Print the html page using print Dialog.

Comment: Can we see your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some kind of an html renderer in order to print it. either IEExplorer (look into shdocvw.dll and mshtml.dll) or Awesomium etc...
good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the Print() method of the WebBrowser Class in C# to do this. Just put the content to the WebBrowser Control like so:

`webBrowser1.DocumentContent = openfiledialog.FileName;`

Then just call the "webBrowser1.Print();" method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print.aspx

Comment: It is supported in Windows form not in wpf

Comment: you can add in References "System.Windows.Forms". Then add "using System.Windows.Forms" in your class. All will be okay. Do not forget to push the button("This answer is useful"). :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer MIcrosft.mshtml com object

mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = rptPreview.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2; doc.execCommand("Print", true, null);